# How to store the output of C program using Bash shell scripting

Tags: c, bash, shell, output, sh

This is my C program

```
int main(){

int n;
while(1){
    printf("Enter n:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    switch(n){
        case 1: int t; 
            scanf("%d",&t);
            if(t<10)
            printf("true");
            else printf("false");
            break;
        case 2: char c;
            scanf("%c",c);
            if(c=='a') printf("true");
            else printf("false");
            break;
        case -1: break;
    }
        if (n==-1) break;   
}

return 0;
}
```

This is my bash shell script

```
./a.out << 'EOF'
1
4
2
b
-1
EOF
```

This will execute the code but doesn't save the output

```
./a.out > outputfile
```

The above code will save the output, including "Enter n".

I want to execute the code and save only true/false part (i.e excluding all the other printf's). How to store the output of a file along with giving inputs to it?

Comment: If you know the inputs, avoid unnecessary printf's and you can achieve what you want.

Comment: @SudoPehpeh : Your program writes to stdout, so `outputfile` will contain all the `printf` results. If you don't want to have everything in stdout, write the unneeded part to stderr instead, i.e. `fprintf( stderr, "everything you do not want to capture")`

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani Normally the file is supposed to be run by the user, so the print statements are necessary to tell the user what to input. shell scripting code is to just check for a given input whether the code is giving the correct input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an alternative for a.out, that I can use for testing. `is_odd.sh` looks for odd umbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

exitfalse() {
   echo $*
   echo false
   exit 1
}

exittrue()
{
   echo $*
   echo true
   exit 0
}

[ $# -eq 0 ] && exitfalse I wanted a number
[[ $1 =~ [0-9]+ ]] || exitfalse Only numbers please
(( $1 % 2  == 0 )) && exitfalse Even number
exittrue Odd number
```

Using this verbose script gives a lot garbage

```
#!/bin/bash
testset() {
   for input in john doe 1 2 3 4; do
      echo "Input ${input}"
      ./is_odd.sh "${input}"
   done
}

testset
```

How can you have the same output and only false/true in a file? 
Use `tee`to send output to the screen and to some process that will do the filtering:

```
testset | tee >(egrep "false|true" > output)
```

I think above command fits best with your question, I would prefer to see the input strings:

```
testset | tee >(egrep "Input|false|true" > output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./a.out < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: okay. But what about saving only the output of the switch case?